# Is there any way to set a binding on a TextBlock Span

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I would like to use a several Span elements inside a TextBlock and have the content of the spans set by binding.  I don't think this is possible, but wanted to double check here first.

Answer (score 6):

@walkman123 is correct that you can't bind to `span` elements in XAML.

You might want to consider using `Run` elements rather than `span` elements as you can bind to these from within a `TextBlock`.

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="Arial" Width="400" Text="Company Information">
  <Run FontFamily="Courier New" FontSize="24" Text="{Binding CompanyName}" />
  <LineBreak/>
  <Run FontFamily="Courier New" FontSize="18" FontStyle="Italic" Text="{Binding CompanyAddress}" />
  <LineBreak/>
  <Run FontFamily="Courier New" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding CompanyPhone}" />
  <LineBreak/>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Span element value cannot be binded, because it is not a Framework Element, but Inline Element.

Only Framework Elements can be bound.